# In an if statement I would like to check a cell and if "water" is somewhere in the cell, it is true

Tags: excel, string, if-statement

I am trying to use the if statement but do not want to validate the entire cell value, just check for a specific word like "water".

In an if statement I would like to check a cell and if "water" is somewhere in the cell, it is true

e.g.: Cell B3 value = "The water is blue"

The following formula is incorrect, but illustrate: @if(B3,"*water*", "true", "false")

So with "*water*" I am trying to search for the word water and ignore the other characters

Any suggestions?

Comment: What programming language do you use?

Comment: I'm ***guessing*** you're working with Excel? If the tag I added is wrong, then please [edit] your question to correct it.

Comment: Try using `FIND()` or `SEARCH()` --> the first one is **case sensitive** and does not allow **wildcard characters** while the latter is exactly the opposite. Thats said based on your requirements the formula will be  `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("water",A1)),"water","")` or `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("water",A1)),"water","")` or just to return `TRUE` and `FALSE` --> `ISNUMBER(FIND("water",A1))` or `ISNUMBER(SEARCH("water",A1))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya find() does not need wildcards - see my answer posted prior to your comment.

Comment: We were in the same time sir, while i was writing your post appeared. Also I have wrote that `FIND()` is case sensitive and does not allow wildcards.!! Also per OP needs to return `TRUE` & `FALSE` and not a number you may need to wrap within `ISNUMBER()` instead of using `IFERROR()`.

Answer (score 0):

So like this:

[image]

You can add an if() for any positive value and put a 1 or whatever you need, find() returns the starting character position.